# Which XML files is to be used for different screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on android app and I have created different screens for different layouts.There are  3 types of `Android XML` files, `Android Layout XML` and `Android values XML`.Which one is to be select. Please suggest

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only Layout XML for layout  and for landscape create another  folder layout-land inside res folder and create layout of same name with different design suitable in landscape mode. And use different layouts with same name and same Id of all the child view.then android automatically pick when orientation changes

use this for reference
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range